# MYSQL trigger for Cascading Delete : Workaround needed

Tags: mysql, triggers

Consider 3 Tables -

```
Student(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(100));
Test(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(50), MaxMarks INT, TestDate DATETIME);  
StudentTakesTest(TestId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Test(Id), StudentId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Student(Id), MarksObtained FLOAT, MarksObtainedInPercentage FLOAT);
```

Every time a student takes test, the average of all the tests taken by a particular student is stored in an index table. I am doing this with the help of triggers.

I have applied 3 triggers on `StudentTakesTest` table that is `AFTER INSERT`, `AFTER UPDATE` and `AFTER DELETE`. The INSERT and UPDATE Triggers are firing since the actions are done directly on the StudentTakesTest table. The DELETE trigger won't fire since the action is not directly on the `StudentTakesTest` table, it is a Cascading delete that happens when an entry in the `Test` table is deleted.

Is there a work around or a logic that could help me run the trigger on Cascading Delete of the table entries as well?

Comment: Why? Let's say you have 100,000 students. Each student takes 20 tests annually, and you want to collect data for 50 years. This is 100,000,000 rows. It's at about this point that you might want to start using some kind of 'index' table, but not before.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use on delete cascade in your foreign key constraints in studenttatkestest?

Comment: @Strawberry, I have just described the scenario as simple as possible. Test actually belongs to a Topic, Topic to a Chapter, Chapter to a Subject. A subject can have up to 15 chapters, a chapter can have up to 15 topics and each student answers all questions related to topics in the test. The tables grow exponentially when a student takes test. I am working on indexing since there will be a lot of data and I have to calculate the performance of a student from Subject, Chapter, Topic and Test perspectives.

Comment: @P.Salmon, MYSQL doesn't support it.

Comment: Yes it does what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: It does support cascading delete through referential constraint. What I'm saying is It does not fire the ON DELETE trigger if the deletion happens due to cascading. I am asking for a workaround for this.